# SQL Server 2016 vs Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-11, sql-server-2016, reporting-services-2016

I have several reports created with multi value parameters.  They are deployed to the report manager and run fine from chrome.  When ran from Internet Explorer 11, when a parameter is chosen, I cannot click on the down arrows or scroll bar of the multi valued param.  When I do it closed the param and would not scroll. I can use the scroll wheel but clicking does not work.  This only happens in IE 11 which happens to be what 90 percent of our users use.  Any ideas on a fix?  This is SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Try good ole compatibility mode?

Comment: Yea, I tried that and that doesn't work either.